# How to remove white space below footer?

Tags: html, css

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UHMZ.png) white space below the footer, it is in the html 
and i cant understand how to remove it, i have on my css

```
html {
   margin:0
   padding:0
}
```

The button has a div, maybe if I extend it i could remove the blank space>
How could I do that maybe?

Comment: Your content isnt big enough to fill the content. You might want to set your min height of the bpdy/html to 100% of the viewport

Answer (score 0):

Select Everything(*) and do not forget to close your code with semi colon (;).

```
   *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
```